# Gridview of ImageViews that each image opens a different activity

Tags: java, android, gridview, imageview

I'm trying to implement a Gridview which displays an array of predefined ImagesViews from drawables and I want each ImageView when onClick to open an activity, below you can see my code...

ImageAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

//CLASS TO FILL THE GRID VIEW AS ADAPTER AT activity_main.xml WITH IMAGES OF OUR CATEGORIES

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.test_icon_1, R.drawable.test_icon_2,
            R.drawable.test_icon_3, R.drawable.test_icon_4,
    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        return imageView;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
            <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/grid_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
```

I can't find a way to implement this and make it understand which activity to open, since later on I want to implement this by showing ImageViews requested from an SQLite database and open specific activities when clicked.

I'm thinking of doing that by passing an integer e.g. 1,2,3,4... and take that as an SQL parameter for parent_category_id and display dynamicaly the child_categories_ids

Answer (score 0):

There is a really easy solution to this. Instead of making your underlying set of values for the Gridview an Integer array, define a custom class that also specifies which activity to open. Such as:

```
    class MyGridviewClass{

    public MyGridviewClass(Class<? extends Activity> mActivityToOpen, Integer mGridviewImageLoc) {
        this.mActivityToOpen = mActivityToOpen;
        this.mGridviewImageLoc = mGridviewImageLoc;
    }

    public Class<? extends Activity> getmActivityToOpen() {
        return mActivityToOpen;
    }

    public void setmActivityToOpen(Class<? extends Activity> mActivityToOpen) {
        this.mActivityToOpen = mActivityToOpen;
    }

    public Integer getmGridviewImageLoc() {
        return mGridviewImageLoc;
    }

    public void setmGridviewImageLoc(Integer mGridviewImageLoc) {
        this.mGridviewImageLoc = mGridviewImageLoc;
    }

    private Class<? extends Activity> mActivityToOpen;
    private Integer mGridviewImageLoc;

}
```

Now, assign the activity you want to open to each element in the gridview. This should make it much easier for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand your code, but i cannot specify which activity to open staticaly. Because im going to retreive a category from the SQLite db. If the category is empty, im not gonna display the imageview hence the activity